# Adding a SubDocument located in a SharePoint site to a WordDocument

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, vsto

I have a requirement to add several SubDocuments into a Word document. The subdocument is located on SharePoint.
When trying this through the Word UI, this works as expected (the SubDocument is added and it 'links' to the document hosted on SharePoint):

[Manually adding a subdocument - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goztc.png)

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and have a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll version 8.7.0.0 (Office 2016 64bit). The documents are hosted on a SharePoint 2013 environment (although I don't think that matters as I have the same results on a SharePoint 2010 environement).

I currently have the following code (I used a random SharePoint hosted Word document I found online as I currently do not have access to my companies SharePoint environment):

```
using MOIW = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
static void Main(string[] args) {

    var wordApp = new MOIW.Application();
    wordApp.Visible = true;
    var subDocument = "https://www.stb.gov.sg/assistance-and-licensing/Documents/MIP_Terms_and_Conditions.docx";

    var masterDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"c:\test\master.docx");
    masterDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = MOIW.WdViewType.wdOutlineView;
    masterDoc.Subdocuments.AddFromFile(subDocument);
    masterDoc.SaveAs2(@"c:\test\master_with_subdoc.docx");
}
```

When running this code, I get the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>    HResult=0x800A1436
>    Message=Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?
>   (https://www.stb.gov.sg/assistance-and-li)
>    Source=SubDocuments
>    StackTrace:
>     at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Subdocuments.AddFromFile(Object& Name, Object& ConfirmConversions, Object& ReadOnly, Object& PasswordDocument, Object& PasswordTemplate, Object& Revert, Object& WritePasswordDocument, Object& WritePasswordTemplate)
>     at SubDocuments.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sven\source\repos\SubDocuments\SubDocuments\Program.cs:line 23

I recorded a Macro to see how Word adds the SubDocument and this is what I got:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Selection.Range.Subdocuments.AddFromFile Name:= _
        "C:\Users\sven\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.MSO\186723F6.docx" _
    , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
    PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
    WritePasswordTemplate:=""
End Sub
```

So it looks that Word opens the SharePoint file and then uses the locally created (temp) file to insert the SubDocument.

I tried to do the same, but when I do this, the SubDocument does not refer to the SharePoint document but to the local file.

```
using MOIW = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var wordApp = new MOIW.Application();
    wordApp.Visible = true;
    var subDocLocation  = "https://www.stb.gov.sg/assistance-and-licensing/Documents/MIP_Terms_and_Conditions.docx";
    //open the file stored on SharePoint 
    var subDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(subDocLocation);
    //get the local file (for this test I made sure there were no other files in the folder)
    var tempFile = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\sven\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.MSO", "*.docx")[0];

    var masterDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"c:\test\master.docx");

    masterDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = MOIW.WdViewType.wdOutlineView;

    //add the subdocument using the local file
    var subdoc = masterDoc.Subdocuments.AddFromFile(tempFile,
        false,
        false,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        false,
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty);

    masterDoc.SaveAs2(@"c:\test\master_with_subdoc.docx");
}
```

[adding subdocument from templocation using code - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymoi2.png)

I found a 10-year old [MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe2b0f84-5af6-41d7-902a-a8b5abdc3978/word-master-subdocuments-problem-with-sharepoint-documents?forum=vsto) that describes the same issue but does not provide a real solution.

> As I was just about to post this question I thought of a workaround by using the OpenXML approach and (manually) changing the path of the file to the online location (it's in the document.xml.rels part). 
>   This seems to do the trick (you cannot change the 'Path' or 'Name' properties of the SubDocument using the Word Object Model as they are read-only properties)
>   If no solution using the Word Object Model can be found, I will implement it like this and update the question with the code.